# Jersey/REST API - Server side cache example

Tags: java, rest, caching, jersey

As a complete novice, I've written the below REST endpoint which provides a very basic server side cache. Idea is to ensure clients do not get data which is older than 5 seconds. I am caching data from an external (3rd party) service so clients cannot get the data directly due to load limits.

Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
public class MyRESTService {

    private static int count = 1;
    private static LocalDateTime lastUpdateTime = LocalDateTime.now();

    @GET
    @Path("/verify")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response verifyRESTService(InputStream incomingData) {

        String response = null;

        if (Duration.between(lastUpdateTime, LocalDateTime.now()).toMillis() > 5000) {
            lastUpdateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
            response = "Here's your new count " + ++count;
        }
        else {
            response = "Here's your count " + count;
        }

        return Response.status(200).entity(response).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, there are issues related to concurrency. Multiple threads might end-up incrementing count in the same interval (making count jump values by more than 1 in the 5 sec interval). You need to guard the if check and the logic under a lock.

Comment: Thanks - What if I don't intend to offer a multi-threaded solution? Is there anything fundamentally wrong with my approach? (Assuming there will always be a single thread)

Comment: Doesn't your service data depend on the incomingData? That's the only thing I see that's missing from being included in the cached output. Can you please update with the problem, if any, that you're seeing?

Comment: I don't need any incoming data. All clients will get the same data so input isn't really required. This code seems to work, I'm just curious about hidden issues. I know there are more complex caching solutions out there (e.g. Cache Control), but I just don't see what they have to offer for my simple use case.

Comment: I guess no other issues then apart from concurrency issues (which I guess you'll have to deal with given you're exposing this as a web service - but yes, you know better of the use case). However, there can be a more efficient implementation for the cache logic - instead of always checking the refresh period, you can have a java.uitl.Timer thread running that reset the count (refreshes the cache) after every 5sec. That would look more elegant I guess.

Comment: Reason for my current approach is that if there are no client requests for say, 2 hours, I don't need to keep the cache warm for nothing. It's like a lazy cache update.

Comment: I don't think that your simplified example fits with what you really want to achieve. The rest service is named 'verifyRESTService' and has some input data, so I would expect that the output depends on the input data and caching a single value will not be sufficient. How would your code look like in case you do cache the output for different inputs separately?